# how to represent integer infinity in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, integer, infinity

I have a variable with type annotation as ***int***. I want to assign it an arbitrary large value as default. If it was a ***float***, I could have used ***math.inf***. However, what should I use if variable is integer?

```
def calc(x: int = math.inf):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

there I no way you can do so. You can just stick to float.